# Authenticating to Office 365 Outlook IMAP using MailKit fails for a specific user

Tags: outlook, office365, imap, mailkit

For a lot of customers, we connect to the Office 365 Outlook IMAP server, and that works just fine. However, for one customer now it does not work. I can log into portal.office.com with the username and password, and go to Outlook there and see the mailbox, but I can't for the life of me get this to work in my code. This is my code:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var logger = new ProtocolLogger(stream, false);

using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient(logger))
{
    try
    {
        client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, true);
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.Authenticate(@"SVC_CubitDLE@lyse.no", @".whb----%RS*,H^");
        var inbox = client.Inbox;
        inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        var uids = await inbox.SearchAsync(SearchQuery.NotSeen);
    } catch (Exception exc){
        exc.Dump();
        stream.Position = 0;
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        reader.ReadToEnd().Dump();
    }
}
```

I tried with and without the line `client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");`.

The exception thrown is `AuthenticationException` with message `LOGIN failed.`

The log emitted in the steam is:

```
S: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [UABSADAAUAAyADYANABDAEEAMAAxADkAOAAuAEYAUgBBAFAAMgA2ADQALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]
C: E00000000 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
S: E00000000 OK CAPABILITY completed.
C: E00000001 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN AFNWQ19DdWJpAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASF4=
S: E00000001 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
C: E00000002 LOGIN SVC_CubitDLE@lyse.no ".whb----%RS*,H^"
S: E00000002 NO LOGIN failed.
```

Any idea to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks as if you've pasted an actual password, twice. Might want to change that straight away.

Comment: (FYI, `AUTHENTICATE PLAIN` contains the password base64-encoded, too.)

Comment: I've looked at the actual question now, and I think this is a matter for Microsoft's customer service. The IMAP parts look faultless.

Comment: I missed the base64 part, but the other passwords above is not the correct ones. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party and I'm assuming that the username and password strings have been obfuscated now(?), so I can only ask: does the user name or password contain any unicode characters? The only thing that I can think of that might break `AUTHENTICATE PLAIN` is if MailKit's `SaslPrep` implementation is wrong somehow, but that would require the username or password to contain unicode characters which does not seem to be the case.

Comment: If you are able to do it, you might find answers by using a program like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to sniff packets of a successful login using Outlook or Thunderbird or something and then comparing to the commands that MailKit is using.

Comment: Nope, absolutely no unicode chars in the password.

Comment: Are all users in the same domain?  Is this a special service account?  It may have different security requirements set on it.

Comment: FWIW, Office365 seems to have a "Allow less-secure apps" setting like GMail has that, if not set, will not allow a user to authenticate over IMAP/POP3/SMTP using anything other than OAuth2.

Comment: @ØyvindBråthen was this ever solved?

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that IMAP is disabled for that user. I would check to see if that's enable if you have access to the AD.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/pop3-and-imap4/configure-mailbox-access?view=exchserver-2019) an article